# Drop down list inside of HTML table List in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a newbie to MVC, I have some problem to populate a dropdown inside of a html table. I have my classes like

```
Public Class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}

    public Employee() {}
    public Employee(Employees emp)
    {
        this.EmployeeId=emp.EmployeeId;
        this.EmployeeName=emp.EmployeeName;
        this.Country=emp.Country;
    }
}

Public Class Employees : List<Employee>
{
    Public Employees()
    {
        MyEntities entities=new MyEntities();

        foreach(Employees emp in entities.Employees)
        {
            this.Add(new Employee(emp));
        }
    }
}
```

In the same way I have `Country and Countries classes` also which is having `CountryId and CountryName`. I am binding list of Employees in my View from the controller like,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Employees emp = new Employees();
    return View(emp);
}
```

this is showing me the employees data from my db. In the last row of my table I have manually added a row for `Adding a new employee`, by entering the `EmployeeName` and selecting `Country` from a dropdownlist.

The problem is here in the dropdown. I have already displayed a list of employees in my view. Is it possible to one more list of `Countries` in my dropdown. And also I need to bind the selected country to the `employee.country` property.

I am much more comfortable with webforms, but in MVC I dont know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `Employees` pass model that contain both collections:

```
  class IndexViewModel
  {
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
    public IEnymerable<Conuntry> Countries {get;set;}
  }
```

Than construct and pass it to view

```
  return View(new IndexViewModel { 
     Employees = employeeRepository.GetAll(),
     Countries = GetAllCountries()
  }
```

Than render countries dropdown using `Model.Countries`

Comment: Thanks it is working, can you help me to bind it in a drop down, am able to get the `Countries` like `Model.Countries`, but when I tried to bind it like `@Html.DropDown("Country",(IEnumerable<Mvc.Models.Country>)Model.Countries` it is showing error.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one.....

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Cert", (SelectList)ViewData["Countries"], "--Select--", new { @class="dropdownlist" ,id = "Country" })
```

Models

```
 public string Certification{ get; set; }
```

Controller

```
 var Country = new SelectList(new[]
            {
                new {ID="1",Name="India"},
                new{ID="2",Name="Nepal"},
                new{ID="3",Name="Srilanka"},...etc
            });
            ViewData["Countries"] = Country ;
```